# How can I make an ion-item responsive?

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework

Basically, I'm trying to make an ion-item being responsive. Instead of this:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yROA.png)

Should be something like this:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUkgE.png)

As you can see, there's information lost.

Is possible to adapt ion-item to something like the second photo?

I tried to add text-wrap, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding an ion-grid an ion-row elements.

Code should look like this:

```
<ion-grid [fixed]="true">
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      ...
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```